# Resetting counter? What have I done wrong? *beginner*

Tags: python, loops, logic, counter, replit

Apparently, when this program asks for another number it adds all the numbers in the input together until the end of the program. How would I go about resetting the counter for this program? Where did I go wrong? [here's my code in replit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO4Ic.jpg)

Comment: Please format your code into the question, not as a linked image

Answer (score 0):

if again != 'y' :

sum = 0.0

break

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if you want the sum to reset when the user inputs 'y', you have to initalize `sum = 0` in the **while** loop.

Answer (score -1):

change line 9, so you won't reuse the previous `sum` value

```
sum = number_one + number_two
```

Comment: Please don't use `sum` as a variable name, it will overwrite the builtin `sum` function.